# Count objects assigned to the category in a django cycle

Tags: django

I've a cycle in my template, which get's all the categories
like this:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h4 class="title1">Категории</h4>
        <ul class="clear-list">
        {% for categ in categs %}
            <li>
                <a href="/advert/adverts.aspx&cat{{ categ.id }}">{{ categ.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</div>
```

And my views.py looks like:

```
def adverts(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['adverts'] =  Advert.objects.all().order_by('-advert_date', '-id')
    args['sections'] = AdvertSection.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    args['categs'] = AdvertCategory.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    args['username'] = auth.get_user(request).username
    return render_to_response('adverts.html', args)
```

Now comes question....

**How to show total count of objects attached to the category?**

Output:

```
Category1
Category2
Category3
```

Expected Output:

```
Category1(115)
Category2(546)
Category3(832)
```

Please help me...

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html ? Specifically, the Counter class.

Comment: It's not what I need, I can perform a count by creating a variable like cat1_count = Advert.objects.filter(advert_category_id=1).count()... but in this case I have to manually write count function for all categories, and if there will be a new category then I'll have to return to views and create a new function, so this is not the proper method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objects attached to your categories are called `Advert`s:

```
{% for categ in categs %}

    {{ categ.name }} ({{ categ.advert_set.count }})

{% endfor %}
```

If you changed the attribute `related_name` of your Adverts in the `Category` `ModelClass` in your `models.py` file you'll have to adjust `advert_set` to the corresponding `related_name`.

For more information about how to access related objects take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager).

Comment: It's also worth adding a select_related() to your query to reduce the number of queries you'd do by adding this. If your field is a ManyToMany, then you'd use prefetch_related().